# Will the use of ConcurrentLinkedQueue cause memory leak?

Tags: java, java-8, concurrentlinkedqueue

I read from a book that the following code will cause memory leak,and the book tells that we should remove the code `queue.add(new Object());` and it will not cause memory leak. but I don't know why. Why?

```
import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConcurrentLinkedQueueMemLeak
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object> queue =
                    new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    queue.add(new Object()); // ① 这一行代码会导致内存泄漏
    Object object = new Object();

    int loops = 0;

    // 休眠10秒，方便打开JDK诊断工具，监控执行前后的内存变化
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    while (true)
    {
        // 每执行10000次进行一次耗时统计，并且输出
        if (loops % 10000 == 0 && loops != 0)
        {
            long elapsedMs = watch.stop()
                .elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.printf("loops=%d duration=%d MS%n", loops, elapsedMs);
            watch.reset().start();
        }
        queue.add(object);
        // ② remove方法删除object
        queue.remove(object);
        ++loops;
    }
}
}
```

before remove the code queue.add(new Object()):

```
loops=10000 duration=588 MS
loops=20000 duration=1881 MS
loops=30000 duration=3175 MS
loops=40000 duration=3452 MS
loops=50000 duration=3784 MS
loops=60000 duration=4424 MS
loops=70000 duration=4761 MS
loops=80000 duration=5733 MS
```

after remove the code queue.add(new Object()):

```
loops=363590000 duration=0 MS
loops=363600000 duration=0 MS
loops=363610000 duration=0 MS
loops=363620000 duration=0 MS
loops=363630000 duration=1 MS
```

Comment: Well, `queue.add(new Object());` will add an object that your code would never remove so `queue.remove(object);` would always have to look for the the object you just added. When you remove that line then `object` will be at the head of a 1-element queue which makes it way easier to remove.

Comment: Btw, note that times taken like you did are not directly comparable as there may be many factors influencing the JVM. For such micro benchmarks you should use JMH.

Comment: On the term "memory leak": I'd not consider this a real memory leak but in general `remove(Object o)` will use `equals()` to find the object to be removed - and the basic implementation of `Object.equals(...)` will use instance identity. Thus, calling `add(new Object())` will add an instance whose identity you don't have (as you have no reference to it) so you can't directly use `remove()` to remove it - you'd need to get the instance from the queue first.

Comment: IMHO not really a memory leak: there is exactly one element that is added to the queue and stays there. And you could retrieve (and remove) that element anytime you want by calling `queue.poll()`

Comment: What book was it?

Comment: @MacGyver，ISBN: 9787111657705

Comment: Not necessarily.  Depending on how concurrency is implemented, dealing with memory on a CPU is often a concern, and that is the focus of improving performance.  Look up the term "context switching".  That is how multiple processes can share a single CPU.

Answer (score 2):

The problem presented in that the book is actually caused by an OpenJDK Bug:  https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8054446.

Kudos to @MacGyver for finding this!!

According to the analysis on the bug report:

> "Reporter is correct - `remove(Object)` will never unlink dead Nodes *if only ever the element at the tail is removed<sup>1</sup>.*"

(Emphasis added)

The bug report shows that the issue was initially raised against Java 8 in 2014, and was fixed in Java 9 in 2019.  The fix was subsequently backported to Java 8 and Java 7.

Note that Java 7 is EOL.  To get a Java 7 release with the fix, I think you will either need an Oracle support contract, or you will need to use a 3rd-party Java 7 release.

---

So to you answer your question:

> Will the use of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` cause memory leak?

If you are using an out-of-date version of Java AND you are repeatedly removing the last element of the queue, then Yes.  Otherwise No.

Solution: use an up-to-date version of Java 7, 8 or later.

I should also point out that using `remove(E)` on a `Queue` / `Deque` is kind of a bad idea anyway.  It is an `O(N)` operation compared with `O(1)` for `add(E)`, `offer(E)`, `remove()`, `poll()`, `element()` and `peek()` (and the equivalent `Deque` operations).

---

<sup>1 - I didn't look at the original source code to see if the leak could occur in other circumstances, but I am prepared to take the official analysis at face value.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This will cause memory leak issue.

**Explanation** :

1. `queue.add(new Object())` adds a new object to the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, which means queue will hold the reference to that object until it is removed.
2. But in the code snippet same object is getting added and removed
   repeatedly, via queue.remove(object) in the while loop.

This might cause the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` to keep the reference to the object indefinitely, even when the object is no longer needed, causing memory leak.

> To fix the memory leak issue, remove the line `queue.add(new Object())` and only add the object instance to the queue, which is
> being used in the while loop.

**Note** : Make sure that the object is removed from the queue after it is no longer needed.